# What are the definitions and distinctions between Project x Program x Portfolio x Product Managers?

Tags: roles, business-analyst, product-manager

What are the definitions, distinctions and relationship between the following roles?

- [Project lead](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/6100/4367)
- Project Coordinator
- Project Manager
- Program Manager
- Portfolio Manager
- *Product Manager (optional)*
- *Business-analyst (optional)*
- *[Team lead](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/6100/4367)* (optional)

(I'm aware that we've touched on this before - [example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/4227/4367), [example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/2753/4367), [example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/1465/4367), [example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/2416/4367), [example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/9121/4367); I'm hoping that we can fold all these answers into one and change it to community wiki as a reference. One answer to rule them all; one answer to enable all to find them, one answer to bring them all and in the stack exchange to bind them.)

*Please add new roles to this question rather than creating new questions; we want to nurture the network effect here*

Comment: Adding to the list of candidate "[canonicals](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/572/canonical-questions-answers-on-project-management)"

Comment: Ahem... the last para indicates the need for a Fantasy PM SE site, doesn't it? Not sure if this is going to be any different from many government projects...

Comment: This questions doesn't have an answer, as each of these roles are defined based on business needs.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've slightly changed the subject to ease the search for this question. Feel free to revert it in case you didn't like :-)

Answer (score 12):

Caveat at the start - these functional titles may be interpreted differently in different organations

**Project Coordinator**
responsible for the adminstration/bookkeeping of a project: preparing budget breakdowns, frequential reporting, supporting standard meetings and

**Project Manager**
responsible for planning, managing and steering the day-to-day activities of the project

**Program Manager**
responsible for coordinating the activities of a number of projects toward a common goal or within the compass of an organisatinal divison (ie all the projects running in the Finance division) or even within a single budget (ie all marketing-related projects)

**Portfolio Manager**
responsible for the Governance of a portfolio of projects, ensuring that the whole remain within projected expenditure and aligned to the assigned goals.

**Product Manager (optional)**
responsible for the ensuring the efficiency and integrity of all processes with respect to a specific product.

**Business-analyst (optional)**
Responsible for ensuring that all business constraints and requirements with respect to a specific product or functional area (Payments, Server Farm X etc.) are fully understood and implemented in any change/project with respect to his/her are of responsiblity.

Answer (score 6):

The PMI view is:

- A **Project Manager** manages a project. They make sure they get done within constraints. He cares most about execution details in day-to-day work.
- A **Program Manager** has a bunch of projects. they may be a Project Manager on one or some of those too.
- A **Portfolio Manager** has a bunch of program. This is more of a strategic "where should our business be in the future" role. This is the least about execution details and most about long-term planning.

And

- A **Product Manager** worries about what the product/service should do. He makes sure the right thing/service that customers want is done. Then the Project Manager manages execution to build it.