# What are the differences between a project assistant, manager, and secretary?

Tags: roles

Is there a difference and if ‘yes’ does there exist a definition of their scopes?

I was asking aunt Google but got the impression from job descriptions that the scope or responsibilities overlap greatly. Is this the case?

Comment: no difference at all,manager sometimes is the owner secretary,the project assistant is the secretary of the project manager and the secretary is always the secretary

Comment: This has been covered multiple times - search for the terms on this SE.  If it hasn't been covered, we need to collect all these questions into a single question with a CW answer. Yes, the scope overlaps greatly; job titles are set arbitrarily, and there is no reason why they would conform to any standard.

Comment: See [project roles](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/9123/4367) among others.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the organization. Larger organizations tend to have more defined job roles. Smaller organizations often have people who wear many hats on a project, and the person who "gets things done" will be tasked with things, regardless of their role.

I've worked as most of those roles one time or another within the same company, so I think I can give an apples to apples view, mind the small sample size.

As a Project Coordinator, most of the work was related to scheduling project deliverables within a part of the project, scheduling meetings, and minor procurement. I would also do meeting notes. I found this similar to secretarial, but that does a disservice to secretarial skills, as I have no formal training in document management which is huge.

As a Project Assistant / Junior PM, I did everything I was doing as a coordinator, but I also did more work communicating with clients and other stakeholders, having more input on the project plan, and doing project financials.